# Is there a simple way to get a array from a object list in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I hope to get a *name* array from a list of *MSetting*, at present, I use Code A to do it, but it's too complex, is there a simple way to do it?

**Code A**

```
  fun getName(aList:List<MSetting>): Array<CharSequence>{
        if (aList.isEmpty()){
            return emptyArray<CharSequence>()
        }else{
            var aa=Array<CharSequence>(aList.size,{""})
            for (index in aList.indices){
                aa[index]=aList[index].name
            }
            return aa
        }
    }
```

**Data**

```
data class MSetting (
        var _id: Long,  
        var name: String,
        var createdDate: Long,
        var description: String
)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution here is using [`map`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/index.html) and then [`toTypedArray`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-typed-array.html):

```
fun getName(aList: List<MSetting>): Array<CharSequence> {
    return aList.map { it.name }.toTypedArray()
}
```

Answer (score 7):

using `map` operator

```
var names = msettings.map { it -> it.name}
```

`names` is a list content all value of `name` from `msettings`

hope this helps

Comment: Hey @gianhtran is there any other method instead of map?

Comment: well kotlin have a lot of method using for collection, depend on your purpose . you can see here https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index.html

Answer (score 1):

map work for me

val names = list.map { it.name }