# Kotlin: How to check if a field in a List of objects is equal to field of another list of objects

Tags: arrays, list, kotlin

basically the title.

If I had to find what I know as a single field,

```
a.any {
    it.name == "user"
}
```

Now I've a listOf(Groups)
Which contains a unique ID

I want to check

if user.groups.anyItemInThisList.UNIQUEID == otheruser.groups.anyItemInThisList.UNIQUEID

My data looks like this

```
{
   "groups":[
      {
         "id":4
         "group":"Test Group",
         "role":"creator",
         "member_count":1,
         "userType":"local"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. That could be interpreted many different ways.

Comment: Sorry, Rephrasing

Comment: @Tenfour04 please check now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50635896/8133524 check this solution hope help for you

Comment: You can do `user.groups.toSet() == otheruser.groups.toSet()`. Or `map` groups to the field you want, before converting it to the set. Is that what you want? Note: this approach is short, but not the most efficient. The "right" solution would depend on your data.

Comment: Hi @Aivean I did not understand what am I doing == and mapping for, I've edited the data I have

Comment: Do you want to find if two collections share at least one common group id, or if all group ids in both collections are identical?

Comment: Yes, I want to know true if Collection of groupA with ID X exists in collectionB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To rephrase your question (making sure I understand correctly), you have two Lists of the same kind of item, and you want to determine if there is any value of the `id` property of an item that appears in both lists.

To do this with simple code, but *O(n^2)* time, you could use this. It iterates all items from `a` and for each item it iterates `b` to see if there are any matches.

```
val result = a.any { x1 -> b.any { x2 -> x1.id == x2.id} }
```

To do it in *O(n)* you can do it with a Set. This creates a set of the names from the first list, and then it only has to iterate the second list once to see if any of the names are in the first set.

```
val aIds = a.mapTo(HashSet(a.size)) { it.id }
val result = b.any { it.id in aIds }
```

Comment: In your second code snippet, `aIds` could be a list, so `b.any { it.name in aIds }` will run in O(N²) time, as a single `contains` check is O(N) for the `List`. You need to ensure that `aIds` is a collection with O(1) `contains` time, to ensure that the whole thing is O(N).

Comment: Ugh, I forgot that `distinctBy` transfers the Set contents to a List before returning. That seems so needlessly limiting.

Comment: I suggest using `mapTo` to avoid creating intermediate collections. Also, you may mention that first approach could be faster if `a` and `b` are known to be small, as it avoids creating intermediate garbage.

Comment: How small could we be talking, list of objects less than 1000?

Comment: If it is always guaranteed that `a.length * b.length < 32` then first approach may be faster, otherwise go with the second one.

Comment: Okay alright, why the number 32?

Comment: It's an arbitrary number just to illustrate the magnitude.

Comment: Alright thank you!